# JpaRepository Centralized Getter Java Design

Tags: java, spring, dao, spring-data-jpa

I've been wondering about how to deisn a centralized service for all object search/getter methods for all JpaRepository classes.

so lets say that now i have:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{}
public interface SchoolRepository extends JpaRepository<School, Long>{}
```

..and bunch of other object repositories.

Now I have a separate service classes that I inject corresponding Repository bean. This introduces issues with circular dependencies: for instance when I need to query school in inside `StudentService` and I also need to query student in `SchoolService` (both can't have other service in it) So, I want to have it centralized in a single `SearchService` which only have 1 method, search(Object, Predicate) and have all `Repositories` injected to this 1 class. Then all services would use inject only this `SearchService`.

Can anyone help suggest one good design? Right now I can only imagine creating multiple search methods like `searchStudent(Predicate)` and `searchSchool(Predicate)` in `SearchService` and call the proper method when searching objects.. but it kinda doesn't look so elegant..... Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Now I have a separate service classes that I inject corresponding Repository bean" -> do you mean that you're injecting service classes into your repositories? If so, don't do this. Only inject all the necessary repositories into the services.

Comment: no, I mean, for example in StudentService i have only StudentRepository injected, for SchoolService, I have SchoolRepository injected. But I may want to have SchoolService injected as well into StudentService, and the other way around which could cause circular dependency

Comment: Generally, you should avoid injecting the services into other services. Why do you need access to the service rather than to the just the underlying repository?

Comment: because the search/getter method is in the services

Comment: for example, in SchoolService, one of the method may need to call something like getAllStudentsWithAge() and I would then declare this method in StudentService, I dont want to repeat the logic in SchoolService using StudentRepository...

Comment: a method like `getAllStudentsWithAge()` should probably be a *repository* method, if there is a corresponding service method, it should essentially just be a pass-through... Using the repository method from both services shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: right, if age was one of the few search factor. In my real case, i have bunch of factors and I needed to use a method that receives predicates, something like search(Predicate), so i dont have to write a lot of getAllStudentsWithPropertyX()

Answer (score 0):

> So, I want to have it centralized in a single SearchService which only
>   have 1 method, search(Object, Predicate) and have all Repositories
>   injected to this 1 class. Then all services would use inject only this
>   SearchService.

I do not think you should want this. This violates SRP since your SearchService will soon know about every other entity in your software.

Think about adding caching here. What if you want to cache students, but not schools? In your scenario you will have to put caching logic into your SearchService also. And this service will turn soon into know-it-all since it will have to know how to cache everything and everywhere.

If you want to share search logic, make some abstract repository with it and inherit your repositories from this abstract one. In this case you will be able to easily override default implementation to include some additional search logic in each of the concrete classes.